# Error relacionando modelos con Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

Estoy intentando hacer una base de datos *noSQL* de una tienda de libros. Cuando estoy definiendo el esquema de libros, intento relacionar ese modelo con otro modelo ya creado y obtengo un error en consola.

Lo que trato de hacer es salvar la información proveniente del frontend del libro pero la información del autor, y genero guardarla con un id diferente pero que estén relacionados con el modelo de libro.

Mi promela es que al momento de salvar el libro en la base de datos (se guarda pero no hace referencia ni al author ni al genre.

**controller.js**:

```
    const create = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'No data',
    });
  }
  const book = new Books(req.body);
  book.save((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err.message,
      });
    }


    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Book created succesfully',
      result,

    });
  });
};
```

**model.js**:

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Author', 
  },
  numberInStock: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    default: '/path/to/default/image.png',
  },
  genre: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Genre',  
  },
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', bookSchema);
```

**view.ejs**:

```
 <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>Add a New Book</h1>
            <form action="/books/new/create" method="post">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="book_name"> Book Name: </label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="name">
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Author</label>
                            <select class="form-control"  name="<%= author._id %>">
                            <% author.forEach(function(authors){ %>
                            <option><%= authors._id %></option>
                            <% }); %>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Genre</label>
                            <select class="form-control"  name="<%= genre._id %>">
                            <% genre.forEach(function(genres){ %>
                            <option><%= genres.name %></option>
                            <% }); %>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="numberInStock">Number in stock: </label>
                            <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="numberInStock">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="image">Image: </label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="image">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la forma en que pretendes realizar la relación entre modelos.

Voy a hacer algunas suposiciones dado que no aportas mucha información sobre el modelo *Genre* y el modelo *Author*.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea relacionar 1 modelo (*Book*) de Mongoose con otros 2 modelos también de Mongoose (*Author* y *Genre*), además se desea añadir dicha relación cada vez que se crea un nuevo documento tipo *Book* a la colección *books* de MongoDB. Todo esto usando Mongoose, Express y NodeJS.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar las relaciones (referencias) debemos especificar un campo en nuestro esquema que guarde una relación con el valor de `_id` de otro documento de nuestra base de datos.

Mongoose nos permite realizar dicha referencia asignándole a un campo el valor de un documento de tipo `ObjectId` y con una clave `ref` que indica el nombre del modelo al cual se hace referencia.

```
const miSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    campo: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Modelo'} //<= Aquí realizamos la relación
    ...
});
```

También deseo aclarar la diferencia entre *Schema* y *Model* en Mongoose.

Muchas veces he visto que tienden a usar la palabra Modelo y Escquema de forma intercambiada, lo cual es erróneo y puede llevar a confusiones.

Un [Esquema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html), es un objeto que tiene una relación directa con una colección en MongoDB y además sirve de molde o patrón para los documentos de dicha colección.

Un [Modelo](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) en cambio, es un constructor (compilado a partir de un esquema) que permite crear y leer documentos de la colección con la cual se relaciona el esquema.

Hecha esta acotación, vamos a trabajar en el problema.

Supongamos que tienes un archivo llamado **book.model.js** que establece tu esquema y exporta el modelo tipo **Book**.

También has de tener un archivo llamado **author.model.js** y otro llamado **genre.model.js**

Nótese que los nombres de los *modelos* son en singular, ya que estamos hablando de homónimos para un (1) documento. Con esto, simplemente separamos lo que se refiere a colecciones (*books*, *authors*, *genres*) de documentos (*Book*, *Author*, *Genre*).

En nuestro archivo *book.model.js* podemos realizar la relación con el modelo *Author* y con el modelo *Genre* de la siguiente manera:

**book.model.js**:

```
//ES5
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String,
        required: 'Name is required'
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Author',
        required: 'Author is required'
    },
    numberInStock: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: '/path/to/default/image.png'
    },
    genre: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObectId,
        ref: 'Genre',
        required: 'Genre is required'
    },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
```

Como podemos ver en el código he realizado algunos cambios.

Primero debemos notar que el nombre de nuestro esquema es *bookSchema* indicado en singular, lo mismo que el modelo creado a partir de dicho esquema es *Book*, también en singular.

En segundo lugar, he colocado en los campos *author* y *genre*, un documento de tipo *ObjectId* que hace referencia al modelo adecuado según el campo (*author* -> *Author*, *genre* -> *Genre*).

En tercer lugar, he agregado validaciones para los campos *name*, *author* y *genre*, ya que no tiene sentido crear un documento si dichos campos no existen. También he agregado un valor *default* para los campos *numberInStock* e *image*, así cada documento creado tendrá sus campos completos. Si al momento de crear un libro no se tiene el número de los mismos, luego se podrá modificar este campo, ya que al crearlo se ha puesto por defecto en cero. Lo mismo ocurre con la imagen, si al momento de crear el libro no se dispone de una imagen para el mismo, entonces se usa una imagen por defecto.

Por último, pero no menos importante, no he importado (*require()*) ninguno de los modelos *Author* o *Genre* para usarlos en nuestro esquema. Mongoose se encarga de realizar esta relación por nosotros.

También puede llamar la atención que no hago uso de una variable para *Schema* (`const Schema = mongoose.Schema()`). En realidad esto no hace falta, ya que al hacer el *require()* al módulo *mongoose*, podemos usar directamente sus métodos sin necesidad de instanciarlos aparte.

Ahora debemos implementar la funcionalidad de creación de un nuevo documento tipo *Book*. Esta funcionalidad debería estar en nuestro controlador. Supongamos que nuestro controlador se llama **book.controller.js**.

Es una buena práctica separar en archivos diferentes los controladores para las operaciones CRUD de cada entidad. De esta forma podríamos tener también un archivo para manejar las operaciones de autor: **author.controller.js** y otro para las operaciones de género: **genre.controller.js**.

Dicho esto, nuestro controlador para documentos tipo *Book* podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

**book.controller.js**:

```
//ES5
const Book = require('/path/to/models/book.model.js');
const create = (req, res, next) {
    if(!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'No data received'
        });
    }
    const book = new Book(req.body); //<= supongo que los campos en el body del request corresponden con los campos del modelo
    book.save((err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: err.message
            });
        }
        return res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Book created succesfully',
            result: result
        });
    });
}
module.exports = { create }
```

Como se aprecia en el código anterior he realizado unas pequeñas modificaciones a nuestro controlador.

En primer lugar, no utilizo el método *create()* del modelo, esto ya es a elección propia, de cierta menera no me gusta ser repetitivo. Dado que la sentencia `const book = new Book(...)` crea una instancia del modelo, simplemente uso el método `save()` directamente.

Por otro lado, hago una pequeña comprobación en `if(!req.body)`, solo para saber si hay datos a procesar.

Por último, aunque esto lo decides de acuerdo a tu diseño, yo estoy enviando al frontend un mensaje indicando si hubo error o si el resultado es satisfactorio, además, si es satisfactorio entonces envío el resultado de la operación, que en este caso será el nuevo documento tipo *book* que ha sido añadido a la colección *books* de nuestra base de datos.

De esta forma ya tienes un modelo *Book* relacionado con el modelo *Author* y el modelo *Genre*.

**Nota**

Para que esto funcione, el cuerpo del *body* de nuestra solicitud ha de contener los valores necesarios para poder crear el documento. Los **valores** correspondientes a *author* y *genre* deben ser valores del campo **`_id`** del documento respectivo.

Espero que esta respuesta te ayude a aclarar tus dudas.

Comment: gracias por la explicación me sirvió de mucho pero obtengo otro error cuando intento guardar `error: "Books validation failed: author: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "Dan Brown" at path "author", genre: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "Techno-thriller" at path "genre""` verifique en los modelos que la referencias estuvieran bien y en las rutas todo parece bien

Comment: El error es claro, estás pasando el nombre del autor en vez del `_id`. Lo mismo ocurrirá con el género. Debes cambiar eso en el front. Si pudieras mostrar cómo recuperas los autores yblos géneros que envías desde el front, te podría dar una respuesta.

Comment: Ok puse el template que utilizo en la pregunta , por ejemplo en el lugar del input de genre utilizo como referencia name = genre para después hacer el req.body en el controlador como sería ?

Comment: Pues lo ideal es que muestres un elemento `select` donde el usuario pueda escoger el nombre del autor que ya está almacenado en la base de datos. Lo mismo con el campo *genre*. Si el autor no existe en la BD o el género no existe, entonces debe haber una forma de agregar un autor y/o un género ANTES de poder añadir un libro a la colección. Por eso en mi respuesta yo *asumo* que ya tienes una colección de autores y una colección de géneros. El usuario elige el autor y el género de los que ya están en la base de datos.

Comment: Recuerda que un elemento `select` tiene un campo `value` donde puedes poner el `_id` del autor, y mostrar el nombre del mismo al usuario. Lo mismo para el `select` de género. Debes escribir este código de forma dinámica cuando usas `ejs`. Voy a editar la respuesta para mostrarte cómo conseguirlo

Comment: pensé que podía guardar toda esa información en el mismo template en el momento de la creación del book tanto el renglón de genre como author

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91929/discussion-between-liantony-p-and-mauricio-contreras).

Comment: cambie la pregunta como esta escrito el código ahora

Answer (score 0):

ya encontre el error estaba en la forma en que mandaba la información de nuevo al backend

```
<div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Add a New Book</h1>
                <form action="/books/new/create" method="post">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="book_name"> Book Name: </label>
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Author</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="author">
                                <% authors.forEach(function(author){ %>
                                <option value="<%= author._id %>" ><%= author.name %></option>
                                <% }); %>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Genre</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="genre" id="genre">
                            <% genres.forEach(function(genre){ %>
                            <option value="<%= genre._id %>" ><%= genre.name %></option>
                            <% }); %>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="numberInStock">Number in stock: </label>
                                <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="numberInStock">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="image">Image: </label>
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="image">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

y la forma en que mandaba la informacion desde el backend al frond en primer instancia

```
controller.createTemplate = (req, res) => {
      Promise.all([
      Author.find({}),
      Genre.find({})
      ])
      .then(([authors, genres]) => {
      res.render('new', { authors, genres });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      })
      };
```